# Command line parameter login for SQL Server Management Studio v18

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it still possible to open SQL Server Management Studio v18 from the command line when using SQL Server authentication?

According to the Microsoft release notes, they removed the -P command line argument due to the security risks. As such is it possible to open the Management Studio using SQL Server authentication from a command line.

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/04/24/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-0-released-for-general-availability/

Command line option -P removed – due to security concerns, the option to specify clear-text passwords on the command line was removed.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? Entering manually is inconvenient , and security is not really an issue as it's juse for debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the password in the "Connect to Server" prompt the first time, click the "Remember password" option and then omit the "-P" command line argument.

Comment: In various programs, such Remote Desktop Manager, it is possible to set the user in every entry (for example 3 entry with 3 different users). in this case there's no way to pass credentials...