# Connect And Run SSMS.EXE from Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

I have needs to open `SSMS.EXE` from a console application and I need to open it with SQL Server authentication. So, user and password will be saved in the app. When user click the app it will open `ssms.exe` and automatically login too.

I tried to open `ssms.exe` from command prompt first to try and to get its parameters.
But the parameters lack Password (-P), when I see other post, there is -P in their parameters.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18 version 15.0.18424.0.
Is this feature already deleted or do I need to setup something?

If this feature already deleted. Can someone suggest a way to make my app work?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: *"I am using SSMS 2018."* This doesn't exist, and you've tagged both [[tag:ssms-2017]] (which also doesn't exist) and [[tag:ssms-18]] in your tags. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: *"I need to open it with windows authentication"*  Then you want the `-E` switch, you don't pass a username and password for Windows Authentication, you use the credentials of the already authenticated user.

Comment: @Larnu o.. sorry i mean Sql Server Authentication

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56369254/21567). (Cannot mark as duplicate because it has no accepted answer). Which refers to [this blog](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/04/24/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-0-released-for-general-availability/), that contains "Command line option -P removed – Due to security concerns, the option to specify clear-text passwords on the command line was removed."

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/ssms-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) as well: *"-P was removed in SSMS version 18.0. Workaround: Try to connect to the server once using the UI and save your password."*

Comment: I can confirm that if you save the password in SSMS, and then pass the `-U` switch, SSMS connects correctly.

Comment: so i need to login first and check remember password?

Comment: Correct, @NickyApriliani .

Comment: is there a way, where i shouldn't login first in ssms ?

Comment: @Larnu do u know where the password stored in file behind ssms
if i could found where the file is maybe i could use program to write password

Comment: That will be encrypted, and Microsoft is *very* unlikely to publish that encryption algorithm, @NickyApriliani ; It would be stupid if they did.